# TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have a piece of Javascript code that assigns string of values to a string array.
Unfortunately if I try to add more than one string to the array, my UI simulator(which runs on JS code) closes unexpectedly. I have tried debugging but I cannot find anything. I am attaching that piece of code where the issue is. may be you guys could find some flaw? On the pop up button click the values I selcted on the UI should get stored in the array and I have a corressponding variable on the server side to handle this string array.

```
_popupButtonClick: function (button) {
                var solutions = this._stateModel.get('solutionName');
                var i;
                var solutionsLength = solutions.length;
                var selectedSolution = [solutionsLength];


                this.clearPopupTimer();
                if (button.position === StatusViewModel.ResponseType.Ok) {

                    for(i=0;i<solutionsLength;i++)
                    {
                        if(this._list.listItems[i].selected)
                        {
                            selectedSolution[i] = this._list.listItems[i].options.value;
                        }
                    }

                    this._stateModel.save({
                        selectedsolutions: selectedSolution,
                        viewResponse: StatusViewModel.ResponseType.Ok
                    });
                } else {
                    this._stateModel.save({
                        viewResponse: StatusViewModel.ResponseType.Cancel
                    });
                }

            }
```

Comment: StatusViewModel is it a javascript object?
if not just make it as "OK" and "CANCEL"

Comment: StatusViewModel is used to handle the button presses. I have a corresponding mapping on the server side also. That is working fine. The problem is in the for loop and if condition is what i am thinking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
var selectedSolution = [solutionsLength];
```

to

```
var selectedSolution = [];
```

This makes your array have an extra item that might be causing a crash.

Also,

you have an

```
if(this._list.listItems[i].selected)
{
    selectedSolution[i] = this._list.listItems[i].options.value;
}
```

But no corresponding else, so your array has undefined values for `i` which are not entering the if.

Maybe adding an empty string might solve it:

```
if(this._list.listItems[i].selected)
{
    selectedSolution[i] = this._list.listItems[i].options.value;
} 
else
{
    selectedSolution[i] = "";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code is looking fine but there seems to be a piece of code which can cause error. For example, you are assigning `var selectedSolution = [solutionsLength];` and for example `solutionsLength is 5` then your loop runs for `5 times`

```
for(i=0;i<solutionsLength;i++) // runs for 5 times
{
    if(this._list.listItems[i].selected)
    {
        // but selectedSolution = [5]; which is on 0th index and from 1st to 4th index it is undefined
        selectedSolution[i] = this._list.listItems[i].options.value;
    }
}
```

So you can try to use `push()` like

```
 selectedSolution.push(this._list.listItems[i].options.value);
```

and on initialization change it like,

```
 var selectedSolution = [];
```

Hopefully this will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks a ton for replying in such quick time. Sure, i ll try your approach and get back to you if it works (even if it doesn't work :p)

Answer (score 1):

```
var selectedSolution = [solutionsLength];
```

keeps the value in the selectedSolution variable.

```
    var selectedSolution = [3];
    selectedSolution[0] gives the values as 3
```

So make it simple

```
var selectedSolution = [];
```